# How to use multiple controller in one directive angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Is it correct to use multiple controllers like below?

```
<div ng-if="actionButtonText=='Confirm'" ng-controller="upsrCtrl" ng-controller="pt3Ctrl" ng-controller="spmCtrl">
    <button ng-click="checkAnswer()" class="button button-confirm-outline">
        {{actionButtonText}}
    </button>
</div>
```

The reason I used these were I make this as footer and the content change dynamically based on different controller.

Comment: What makes you want a design like this? You only have one scope function, checkAnswers(), and why do you need three controllers to handle that

Comment: Header -> Content (Change dynamically) -> Footer

Comment: Header and footer does not need to change, only content will change..but the content got different controller

Answer (score 0):

Try to use custom directive like below. Take a look on a plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ileyNcaSlJYLc2bCbJeq?p=preview

```
app.directive('ifController', function factory($compile) {
  var handler = {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ifController: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      var lastElement = null;
      var update = function() {
        if (lastElement !== null) {
          lastElement.remove();
        }
        var template = '<div ng-controller="' + scope.ifController + '">'+
                '<button ng-click="checkAnswer()" class="button button-confirm-outline">'+
                 '{{actionButtonText}}'+
                '</button>' +
                '</div>';
            var linkFn = $compile(template);
            var content = linkFn(scope);
            element.append(content);
            lastElement = content;
      }
      scope.$watch('ifController', update);
      }
  };
  return handler;
});
```

You can set controller by passing a variable to if-contoller like below:

```
<div if-controller="{{controller}}">
```

This will remove previous build of element and compile a new one with a new one controller. Also you can modify this directive to use it as a wrapper to another directive you with to use (just change template).

Comment: I try first..I will came and give feedback later..thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please, check an updated answer. It's quite different. Hope this one will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `ng-if` handles the switch on which ng-controller to use. And the `ng-click`is the event that triggers the switch.  If thats the case just render all 3 blocks only show based on parentCtrl.

```
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
    <div ng-if="parentCtrl.actionButtonText=='upsrCtrl'" ng-controller="upsrCtrl">
        <button ng-click="checkAnswer()" class="button button-confirm-outline">
            {{actionButtonText}}
        </button>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="parentCtrl.actionButtonText=='pt3Ctrl'" ng-controller="pt3Ctrl">
        <button ng-click="checkAnswer()" class="button button-confirm-outline">
            {{actionButtonText}}
        </button>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="parentCtrl.actionButtonText=='spmCtrl'" ng-controller="spmCtrl">
        <button ng-click="checkAnswer()" class="button button-confirm-outline">
            {{actionButtonText}}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gotta set a parent controller.  Or share a service between the directives.  I would just use a parent controller

Answer (score 0):

Providing wrappers of controller may be a way to find your solution. But if you will see it on element level, An element can not carry more then one one controller.

As i can see there is a way To make one controller the main controller and pass another controller as some other parameter. like `vm` i used in bellow example . Here `vm` is is the page level controller instance(controller of the page where the element is present). use [Isolated scope](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/)  here to access `vm`

```
  <div ng-if="actionButtonText=='Confirm'" ng-controller="upsrCtrl">
    <button ng-click="checkAnswer()" class="button button-confirm-outline" vm='vm'>
    {{actionButtonText}}
    </button>
  </div>
```

But the better way i will suggest is To use more then one directive with its separate controllers and use it. It will be some kind of attribute level directive. which will make your purpose solve.

```
 app.directive('dirUp', function() {
  return  {
   controller: function(scope) {
   //directive controller
     }
   };
});

app.directive('dirDown', function() { 
 return {
  controller: function(scope) {
   //directive controller
         }
       };
     });
```

and in html

```
 <div dir-up use-down></div>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I do not understand.

Comment: use more then one directive, separate directive for each functionality of it.

Comment: I will give feedback later on. Thanks for your answer.